# Using the new reflection API, how to find the primary constructor of a class?

Tags: scala, reflection

You can get all the constructors of a class like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val ctor = typeOf[SomeClass].declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asTerm.alternatives
```

Is there a way to know which one is the primary constructor? Is it always the first in the list?
What happens in case `SomeClass` is defined in Java where the concept of *primary constructor* doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, there's a method on [`MethodSymbolApi`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$MethodSymbolApi) called `isPrimaryConstructor` that does precisely this:

```
val primary: Option[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[SomeClass].declaration(
  nme.CONSTRUCTOR
).asTerm.alternatives.collectFirst {
  case ctor: MethodSymbol if ctor.isPrimaryConstructor => ctor
}
```

In the case of a Java class, you'll just get the first constructor defined in the source file.

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't work inside a compiler phase (post-typer, pre-pickler). I just get null-objects with either `declaration` or `member`. Any ideas?

Comment: False alarm. It does. I passed in `ClassDef.tpe` rather than `ClassDef.symbol.tpe`