# How can I use Scala reflection to get only primary constructor parameters?

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a case class:

```
case class Cow(breed: Breed, gender: Gender)(implicit grass: Pasture) {
  val hasSpots: Boolean
}
```

How can I use reflection at runtime to get back just the list (`breed`, `gender`)? Here's what doesn't work:

```
def getConstructorParams[C](implicit ct: ClassTag[C]) =
  ct.runtimeClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)
  // returns (breed, gender, grass, hasSpots)

def getConstructorParams[C](implicit ct: ClassTag[C]) =
  ct.runtimeClass.getConstructors.head.getParameters.map(_.getName)
  // returns (arg0, arg1, arg2)
```

The first solution includes non-constructor fields (`hasSpots`), which is not what I want. The second solution loses the parameter names. Both methods  also include the curried implicit `grass/arg2` argument, which I also don't want.

Is there some way to get back just the (`breed`, `gender`) fields?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496411/using-the-new-reflection-api-how-to-find-the-primary-constructor-of-a-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [scala-reflect API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect) (I tested it with 2.12 but it may work with other versions), you could do

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getConstructorParams[T: TypeTag] =
    typeOf[T].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)
             .alternatives.head.asMethod // this is the primary constructor
             .paramLists.head.map(_.asTerm.name.toString)


getConstructorParams[Cow] == List("breed", "gender")
```